# Is there a way to train a TensorFlow model on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow, deep-learning

The documentation for porting an already trained TensorFlow Model to iOS is well defined: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/ios

However, nowhere is mentioned if the model:

- can be further trained on the device, or
- can be created from scratch and trained on the device

Is this possible with TensorFlow?

I am aware of other Swift/C++ libraries that offer on-device training, but I am more interested in this technology.

Comment: @Bhaak What "other Swift/C++" libraries that offer on-device training are you aware of? I'm looking for different libraries at the moment, but finding such is really hard as everybody is only writing about using pre-trained models ...

Comment: @Dschee depending on the type of network and technology, there are different libs you can use.
One example is the SwiftAI: https://github.com/Swift-AI/Swift-AI which supports only fully connected neural networks.

Comment: Thanks @Bghaak, I know of Swift AI, but as you say it's very limited. Also it's not mainted anymore (last commit 3 years ago). What I'm looking for is an image classifier based on a CNN. Basically, I've already trained a few models using Create ML which offers good enough results after a minute of training for my use case. Since Create ML isn't available on iOS, I need an alternative. I'd even implement it myself following good instructions, but I can only find tutorials in python and it's hard to know which type the parameters need to be in Swift ...

Comment: @Dschee I see. For the CNN scenario I must say that neither I have managed to found a suitable library. 
I haven't look into the kernels provided from Apple itself (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/convolutional_neural_network_kernels) and I don't know the limitations and purpose, but maybe this will be a good starting point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with CoreML3 and the UpdatableTask, the training on device is now part of the API: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlupdatetask